# HCPC r function - difference between cluster data and cluster visualisation

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm using the package **FactoMiner** and its function **HCPC** in order to create a segmentation of some observations. Then I used the function **plot.HCPC()**, and I observed differences between two alternatives of this function (two alternatives illustrating the same results ...)

`library(FactoMineR) 
 data(USArrests)
 pca <- PCA(USArrests, ncp = 3, graph = FALSE)
 hcpc <- HCPC(pca, graph = FALSE)`

If I used `choice = 'map'`, we see that *Arkansas* is in the green cluster, but if I used `choice = 'tree'`, *Arkansas* is in the red cluster ! (other states of the green cluster stay in the green cluster from map to dendrogram/tree) :

`plot(hcpc, choice = 'map')
 plot(hcpc, choice = 'tree')`

[image]

According to the numeric results (`hcpc$data.clust`), there are 8 observations in the cluster3 (green cluster), which matches the 'map' visualisation (but not the dendrogram/tree visualisation).
Do you know if I did something wrong, if I missed something important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the HCPC function one of the first argument is Consol=T:

> Consol a boolean. If TRUE, a k-means consolidation is performed
>   (consolidation cannot be performed if kk is used and equals a number).

```
library(FactoMineR) 
 data(USArrests)
 pca <- PCA(USArrests, ncp = 3, graph = FALSE)
 hcpc <- HCPC(res.pca,consol=F, graph = FALSE)
 plot(hcpc, choice = 'map')
 plot(hcpc, choice = 'tree')
```

[image: factor map]

[image: tree]

Hope it will help you